# Get wordpress taxonomies in array of arrays

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to store models of automobiles. I created custom taxonomy for this.

It's look like this:

```
Audi
    A4
    A6
BMW
    X1
    X2
Mercedes-Benz
    C-Class
        180
        180d
    E-Class
```

For example, if post about Audi A4 - I mark 'Audi' and 'A4'. Now, at the post I need create name of this car - 'Audi A4'. How I can do this?

I try to use something like this in wordpress loop:

```
$taxonomy = 'automobile';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy, array( "fields" => "ids" ) );
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'include' => $terms );

wp_list_categories( $args ); // Saved inheritance
$auto = get_categories($args); // Without inheritance
```

Comment: if  I got you right, you need a whole tree of taxonomy "automobile", like 180->C-Class->Mercedes-Benz. True?

Answer (score 0):

For any menu-like lists use Appearance->Menu. It will add a bunch of classes such as "current", "current-ancestors". You have to open up screen options and select your taxonomies.